# Finding length of data block in sparse file

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++, ntfs, sparse-file

How can I find length of non-zero data block in sparse file starting from some offset?
Do I have to make some file read or OS can read that information from some metadata which can be cached?
I'm using Windows OS and Visual Studio C++.

Comment: Your question is too ambiguous. Provide some details. What's the problem with using `fseek` and `fread` after it?

Comment: @Mikhail Sparse files are often *very* sparse (e.g. file size is 2**48 of which there are only several megabytes of data), and file offset has some specific meaning (e.g. directly corresponds to a database key). In such a case, a "brute force" approach with fseek/fread will totally trash performance.

Comment: Say I have some data blocks starting at every 128kb of data. These blocks can have variable length. One block can be 1234B long, second 2451B etc. How can I found out what is the length of populated data? This length doesn't have to be exact, for example it can be rounded to whole cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DeviceIoControl` with [FSCTL_QUERY_ALLOCATED_RANGES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command.

Comment: Haven't tested it yet, but this could be just what I was looking for.